# Docker and trying to build an image using Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hopefully someone can help me see the wood for the trees as they say!

I am no Linux expert and therefore I am probably missing something very obvious.
I have a dockerfile which contains the following:

```
FROM node:9.8.0-alpine as node-webapi
EXPOSE 3000
LABEL authors="David Sheardown"
COPY ["package.json", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . /home/vsts/work/1/s/
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

I then have an Azure pipeline setup as the following image shows:

[image]

My issue seems to be the build process cannot find the dockerfile itself:

```
##[error]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/Dockerfile  was found.
```

Again, apologies in advance for my lack of Linux knowledge.. there is something silly I have done or not done ;)

P.S: I forgot to mention in Azure Pipelines I am using "**Hosted Linux Preview**"

**-- UPDATE --**

This is the get sources stage:

[image]

Comment: Can you share you "Get Sources" stage?

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk sorry about the delay, I have been chasing around a lot.  I have a screenshot of the "Get Sources" stage, but I think I have to add to the question (see UPDATE) as I cannot seem to add an image here.. many thanks for helping!

Comment: I need the logs of the Get Sources stage, can you share it also?

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk my apologies, I have included the logs (azure pipelines gave me the option to download as zip)

Here is the link to the zip: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AokoVeppvI53iLFdju-mJAVDCk41og

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, I don't know why but I can't see in the logs which files downloaded in the "Get Sources", can you just take a screenshot like this: https://imgur.com/a/RialbDr

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding the exact path to where the docker file resides on your repository .

```
 Dockerfile: subpath/Dockerfile`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing this absolute path, both within the dockerfile and in the docker build task:

```
/home/vsts/work/1/s/
```

That is a path that exists on the build agent (not within the dockerfile) - but it may or may not exist on any given pipeline run. If the agent happens to use work directory 2, or 3, or any other number, then your path will be invalid. If you want to run this pipeline on a different type of agent, then your path will be invalid.

If you want to use a dockerfile in your checked out code, then you should do so by using a relative path (based on the root of your code repository), for example:

```
buildinfo/docker/Dockerfile
```

Note: that was just an example, to show the *kind of* path you should use; here you should be using the *actual* relative path in your *actual* code repo.

Comment: PS for related but different reasons, the "COPY . /home/vsts/work/1/s/" line in your dockerfile needs to be done differently.